# Delete empty lists from tuple from inside a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples which in turn have 2 elements and a list. I wish to delete the tuples that have empty lists.

```
l = [('Receipt total', []), ('Total Amount (AED)', []), ('Grand total', []), ('Net Amount', []), ('Total Amount', ['593.52']), ('Net total ', []), ('Total', []), ('Gross Amount', []), ('Total Bill (AED)', []), ('Total AED', []), ('Net total in AED', []), ('Total (AED)', []), ('Total Invoice Amount', []), ('Invoice total', []), ('Amount Due', []), ('Grand Total (AED)', []), ('Total Amount Payable', []), ('Net Amt', []), ('Before Total', [('28.26\n', '28.26\n')]
```

Expected output:

```
l = [('Total Amount', ['593.52']), ('Before Total', [('28.26\n', '28.26\n')]
```

I tried :

```
l = [t for t in i if t != [] for i in l]
```

It throws me a `Memory Error`

Comment: Tuples are immutable; you will have to create filtered copies! (_The title is misleading!_)

Comment: `[t for t in l if t[1]]`

Comment: @anurag I don't see why a tuple should be mutated.

Comment: @anurag Never trust the rabbit and the title!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `list` comprehension with unpacking:

```
[(i, j) for i, j in l if j]
```

Output:

```
[('Total Amount', ['593.52']), ('Before Total', [('28.26\n', '28.26\n')])]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have some problem with the input and for the solution you could simply do the following:

```
l = [('Receipt total', []), ('Total Amount (AED)', []), ('Grand total', []), ('Net Amount', []), ('Total Amount', ['593.52']), ('Net total ', []), ('Total', []), ('Gross Amount', []), ('Total Bill (AED)', []), ('Total AED', []), ('Net total in AED', []), ('Total (AED)', []), ('Total Invoice Amount', []), ('Invoice total', []), ('Amount Due', []), ('Grand Total (AED)', []), ('Total Amount Payable', []), ('Net Amt', []), ('Before Total', [('28.26\n', '28.26\n')])]

l = [i for i in l if i[1]]
print(l)
```